# Creating an OS close button? (WinAPI)

Tags: c++, c, user-interface, winapi

I want to create a button that is basically Windows' close button. How could I do this? I want to avoid drawing this myself because I want it to look like that version of Windows' close button. Firefox's tabs do something like this. Thanks

Comment: I have an install of Windows XP at work that uses the Classic Theme, but the Firefox tab close button is red.  So the main window style is ignored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get at Windows XP+ theme specific UI elements via the [`DrawThemeBackground`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773289%28VS.85%29.aspx) API.
Use `WP_CLOSEBUTTON` for the window X button (and one of `CBS_NORMAL/HOT/PUSHED/DISABLED` for its state) and you can draw one wherever you like.

Answer (score 3):

The close buttons on the tabs in Firefox are part of its theme.

If you look in Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\chrome\ there's a zip file called classic.jar.

Inside this zip file is a png file skin\classic\global\icons\close.png.

This png file has the icons for the various states of the close buttons on the tabs:

[image] from [hg.mozilla.org](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/5ee6584ed786/toolkit/themes/winstripe/global/icons/close.png)